# What is the best jQuery deep linking / history plug-in?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, history, deep-linking

I am looking to implement deep linking / back button functionality on a web site that uses jQuery and jQuery UI (tabs, dialogs...). I a new to this so I lack the knowledge to evaluate the different offerings in deep. So far, from what I read on the web, I have narrowed my choice down to **jQuery BBQ** and the **Asual address** plugin.

Is there any other plugin that competes with those 2 ? Which one is the best ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asual address is easier to use than BBQ, and is very fully featured.

According to this question SO says address. Though it might be a little unfair because that answer is almost a year older.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin

Comment: That link is not working anymore, could you refresh it?